# How to display the differences between two files using the diffy gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to compare a local file with an internet file using the `diffy` gem.

```
def show
  require 'open-uri'
  @file1 = File.open('app/assets/files/example.html')
  @file2 = open('http://www.example.com/example.html')
end
```

In my view I have:

```
<%= puts Diffy::Diff.new(@file1, @file2).to_s(:html_simple) %>
```

However, this generates no content in my view apart from my menu bar etc. (no error message either) even though I've made sure the two files do differ. The source code of the page in development is empty where the differences could/should be listed.

I also tried `<%= puts Diffy::Diff.new(@file1, @file2, :source => 'files')` but this produced the error `no implicit conversion of File into String`. What am I doing wrong?

**Update:** The server log displays the following:

```
Started GET "/test_diffy" 
<div class="diff">
  <ul>
    <li class="del"><del>#&lt;File:0x007f369032e038&gt;</del></li>

    <li class="ins"><ins>#&lt;File:0x007f36902eab80&gt;</ins></li>

  </ul>
</div>
  Rendered test_diffy/show.html.erb within layouts/application (2.7ms)
  Rendered shared/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (45.2ms)
  Organization Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 etc.
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (1.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1136ms (Views: 386.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
```

And if I place the `debugger` in the show view, it says for `@file1`: `#<File:0x00000005cb5728>` and similar for `@file2`.

**Update2:** I also tried it with in my view: `<%= puts Diffy::Diff.new(@file1, @file2) %>`. The views still doesn't show any differences and the server log then includes:

```
-#<File:0x007f3692bae4e0>
\ No newline at end of file
+#<File:0x007f3693065c18>
\ No newline at end of file
```

Not sure what that means / what to do!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick glance at https://github.com/samg/diffy, the initializer seems to expect strings as parameters passed. A possible solution would be to turn your inputs into strings before passing them:

```
file1_content = File.open('app/assets/files/example.html').read
file2_content = open('http://www.example.com/example.html').read
@diff = Diffy::Diff.new(file1_content, file2_content).to_s(:html_simple)
```

Then in your view render it with

```
<%= @diff %>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Diffy also offers to compare files: https://github.com/samg/diffy#diffing-files-instead-of-strings. However if I try `@diff = Diffy::Diff.new(file1_content, file2_content, :source => 'files')` it produces the error message `undefined method 'html_safe' for #<Diffy::Diff:0x007f3692feb6c0>` (irrespective whether or not I remove `.read`).  And if I remove `.html_safe` from the view, it does display the view without error but it doesn't display any differences.

Comment: Did you try it without `:source => 'files'`? At this point, it's really only the content of a file, not a file anymore. Maybe rendering `<%= @diff %>` is enough.